# how to apply policy on multiple match in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

```
create table a ( col1 int, col2 int)
create table b (col1 int,col2 int)

insert b
select 1,2
union
select 1,2

insert a
select 1,2
union
select 2,2
```

Expected o/p  (need to join two tables and then get true for first match, false for second match and if not match also false)

1,2,T 
1,2,F
2,2,F

Comment: Please post example content of the tables and an example of the output you expect

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT col1, col2, 
     CASE WHEN (rownumber = 1 AND othercol is not null)
     THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END col3
     FROM
        (
        Select a.col1, a.col2,b.col1 othercol, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(Partition by a.col1 ,a.col2 order by a.col1,a.col2) rownumber 
        from  #a  a
        LEFT JOIN #b b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
        ) t
```